# How do you programmatically set a node's label in neo4jclient?

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have a string `nodeType` which needs to be stored in neo4j as a node's label. In Cypher, this would be

```
CREATE (n:nodeType)
```

where `nodeType` is a string set before this operation. In neo4jclient I have tried

```
.Create("(x:{type})")
.WithParam("type", nodeType)
```

but this is clearly not a correct usage of a parameter, and gives the error

```
Unhandled Exception: Neo4jClient.NeoException: SyntaxError:
Invalid input '{': expected whitespace or a label name
"CREATE (x:{type})"
           ^
```

Moving the label addition to a separate set operation gives the same error.

```
.Create("(x)")
.Set("x :{type}")
.WithParam("type", nodeType)
```

The [official neo4jclient documentation on parameters](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher#parameters) says that "You can create parameters at any point in the fluent query..." but this does not seem to be the case, as the open bracket is not being treated as the start of a paramater by the Cypher engine. What am I doing wrong here?

Since string concatenation is a very, very bad idea, what is the intended method of setting a node's label from a variable in neo4jclient?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples#create-a-user) help?

Comment: No, that is explaining how to set node properties with parameters. I need to set a node's label. In that example, it would be "User" that I need to set with a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Labels can't be parameterized in a cypher query.
To create a node with a dynamic label, you can use [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) with this procedure : `CALL apoc.create.node(['Label'], {key:value,…​})`

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would do:

```
var nodeType = "MyNode";
client.Cypher.Create($"(x:{nodeType})").ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

or if you can't use C# 6:

```
client.Cypher.Create(string.Format("(x:{0})", nodeType).ExecuteWithoutResults()
```

I think it's important to note here that neither of these is using string concatenation. This is what `string.Format` and string interpolation were designed to help with.

logisima is correct that you can't do it via Cypher and your only option would be to shift to APOC if you do need to do it that way, but the string options would be far easier to use

Comment: Just because it isn't technically concatenation doesn't mean the risk is mitigated at all. This code still allows any arbitrary string to be inserted into a Cypher query without any sanitation, which is an injection attack vulnerability.

Comment: Right - so you're referring to injection risks, not string concatenation problems.  You are quite right, I thought as you mentioned concatenation you were referring to memory allocation issues. However - I would argue that this is only an issue *if* you are allowing external users to pass in the `Label` in which case - it makes sense. If your schema is set and the Labels are owned by you, then the risk is not there, as you're not going to take that in from external sources.

Comment: This is the solution we ended up using. Originally we were going to allow the end user to input a label in this application, but because of the injection risk and the complexity of using APOC we decided to just put a list of accepted labels in an `enum`, and have the user pick from those. With the `enum`s we can use string interpolation with little concern.